# Overwriting a column in CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, overwrite

I am trying to overwrite a column in a CSV but can't manage to do that.

```
import os 
import csv
r=len(list(csv.reader(open('C:/Users/KaanPISI/Desktop/seyiresas.csv'))))

open('C:/Users/KaanPISI/Desktop/seyiresas.csv','w')
for i in range(0,r):

       row[i] = row[i].write('/home/nvidia/racecar-ws/src/racecar-
       controllers/deep_learning/data/057/',"%05d"%i,'.jpg')
       i=i+1
```

This ended up deleting all in CSV.

Comment: Duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741723/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to overwrite specific rows in a CSV using the `csv` module; you'll have to write a new file (or overwrite the existing file, as I have below) with your new data.

In the following code, I read the CSV into a list of the rows (`lines`), then you can modify each element as you see fit, then delete the CSV and write a new one with the same name and modified data in `lines`. I'm using the `with()` operators, because `close()` is done automatically.

```
import os
import csv

filepathIn = 'PATH TO YOUR CSV'

# First read the contents of your current file
with open(filepathIn,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

## lines is now a list of each row in the CSV. Modify as needed

# Remove the file and write a new one of the same name
os.remove(filepathIn)
with open(filepathIn,'w',newline='') as output:
    write = csv.writer(output)
    write.writerows(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong mode for the opened file. As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

> (...)'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending(...)

So when you set `w` flag you override your file. All you need to do is change `w` to `a` on this line

```
open('C:/Users/KaanPISI/Desktop/seyiresas.csv','w')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that thing is ok now. But the row[] array isn't working now. How can i make it print to the only first column? How can i make this code work?

Comment: The 'append' mode will just append to the end, so you won't be able to index the row(s) you want to overwrite