# How to delete and replace columns in a csv file by comparing it to other csv files in python?

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a python code to search,delete and replace columns in a csv file 
I have 3 files.

Input.csv:

```
aaaaaaaa,bbbbbb,cccccc,ddddddd
eeeeeeee,ffffff,gggggg,hhhhhhh
iiiiiiii,jjjjjj,kkkkkk,lllllll
mmmmmmmm,nnnnnn,oooooo,ppppppp
qqqqqqqq,rrrrrr,ssssss,ttttttt
uuuuuuuu,vvvvvv,wwwwww,xxxxxxx
```

delete.csv:

```
aaaaaaaa
eeeeeeee
uuuuuuuu
```

replace.csv:

```
iiiiiiii,11111111,22222222
mmmmmmmm,33333333,44444444
```

here is my code:

```
input_file='input.csv'
new_array=[]
for line in open(input_file):
    data=line.split(',')
    a==data[0]
    b=data[1]
    c=data[2]
    d=data[3]
    for line2 in open(delete):
        if (name in line2)==True:
            break
        else:
            for line1 in open(replace):
                data1=line1.split(',')
                aa=data1[0]
                replaced_a=data1[1]
                repalced_b=data1[2]


            if (data[0]==data1[0]):

                data[0]=data1[1]
                data[2]=data1[2]
                new_array=data
                print(new_array)

            else:   
                new_array=data
```

my logic is:

```
1)open input.csv read line by line
2)load elements into an array
3)compare first element with entire delete.csv
4)if found in delete.csv then do nothing and take next line in array
5)if not found in delete.csv then compare with replace.csv
6)if the first element is found in the first column of replace.csv then replace the element by the corresponding second column of replace.csv and the second element with the corresponding 3rd third column of repalce.csv.
7)load this array into a bigger 10 element array.
```

so my desired output is :

```
11111111,22222222,kkkkkk,lllllll
33333333,44444444,oooooo,ppppppp
qqqqqqqq,rrrrrr,ssssss,ttttttt
```

so right now i am facing the following problems:
1)lines that are not present in either replace.csv or delete.csv dont get printed
2)there is a possibility that my input.csv may contain newlines within one entry so reading line by line is a problem,however it is a certainty that the data distributed on the different lines is between quotes.
eg:

```
aaaaa,bbbb,ccccc,"ddddddddddd
ddddddd"
11111,2222,3333,4444
```

any help in bringing the code and my logic together is appreciated.

Comment: do not read csv yourself - use `module csv` - it can work with escaped data that contains newlines. Plenty of posts around how to modify csv - f.e. this one: [overwrite-a-specific-column-in-a-csv-file-using-python-csv-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741723/overwrite-a-specific-column-in-a-csv-file-using-python-csv-module)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing this up a bit:

- read the things you want to `replace` in a dictionary

  - set key to what is in your datas 0th spot, set value as what to replace the 0th and 1st spot of your data with
- read the things you want to `delete` into a set

  - if your data-row start with it: skip row else add it to the output.

Loop over your data and use the both lookups to "do the right thing".

I changed your data a bit to incorperate the mentioned "escaped" data including newlines:

**File creation:**

```
with open("i.csv","w") as f: 
    f.write("""
aaaaaaaa,bbbbbb,cccccc,ddddddd
eeeeeeee,ffffff,gggggg,hhhhhhh
iiiiiiii,jjjjjj,kkkkkk,lllllll
"mmmm
mmmm",nnnnnn,oooooo,ppppppp
qqqqqqqq,rrrrrr,ssssss,ttttttt
uuuuuuuu,vvvvvv,wwwwww,xxxxxxx""")

with open ("d.csv","w") as f: 
    f.write("""
aaaaaaaa
eeeeeeee
uuuuuuuu""")

with open ("r.csv","w") as f: 
    f.write("""
iiiiiiii,11111111,22222222
"mmmm
mmmm",33333333,44444444""")
```

**Programm:**

```
import csv

def read_file(fn):
    rows = [] 
    with open(fn) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"',delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            if row:                     # eliminate empty rows from data read
                rows.append(row)
    return rows 

# create a dict for the replace stuff        
replace = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in read_file("r.csv")}

# create a set for the delete stuff
delete = set( (row[0] for row in read_file("d.csv")) )  

# collect what we need to write back
result = []

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html
with open("i.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            if row[0] in delete:
                continue                                   # skip data row
            elif row[0] in replace:
                # replace with mapping, add rest of row
                result.append(replace[row[0]] + row[2:])   # replace data
            else:
                result.append(row)                         # use as is

# write result back into file
with open ("done.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f,quotechar='"', delimiter= ",")
    w.writerows(result)
```

**Check result:**

```
with open ("done.csv") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
11111111,22222222,kkkkkk,lllllll
33333333,44444444,oooooo,ppppppp
qqqqqqqq,rrrrrr,ssssss,ttttttt
```

Doku:

- [csv.writer/csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: really thanks for this one. your approach seems more robust. Let me experiment with this for a little bit adn then i'll let you know.

Comment: the thing is after the operations are performed i want to dump the array into another array which has more elements out of which a few elements are hardcoded  but csv.writer creates a 4 column csv. any solution to this?

Comment: @anj This changes the "rules / frame" of this question which this answer tries to solve. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. You can reference this question / or answer. Make sure the other question is "self explanatory" enough to pose a question in its own right. You might want to fiddle around with `result` first  - it contains all data as list of list - each inner list is one row -you can extend/append to it to include your "other" data before saving it as csv again. Make sure to search SO first though.

Comment: actually i have mentioned this requirement in my question already. But no worries like you said i'll try to fiddle around with the result to append other data.

Comment: i am trying to make the comparison case insensitive by open the files with lower(). Any idea how to implement this properly?